# Discrete math logic problem

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic

Prove or disprove that $\{\mathcal{M},\;\Phi,\;\neg,\;\bigvee,\;\bigwedge,\Rightarrow \}$ can be reduced to $\{\mathcal{M},\;\Phi,\;\nabla\}$, where x$\nabla$y is equivalent to  $\neg$(x $\bigvee$ y).

I already proved $\{\mathcal{M},\;\Phi,\;\neg,\;\bigvee,\;\bigwedge,\Rightarrow \}$ can be reduced to $\{\mathcal{M},\;\Phi,\;\neg,\;\bigvee\}$.
How to prove $\{\mathcal{M},\;\Phi,\;\neg,\;\bigvee\}$ to $\{\mathcal{M},\;\Phi,\;\nabla\}$

Thank you so much!

Comment: What is $\Phi$?

Comment: I am not sure what it is.

Comment: My professor said it is function statement. eg $\Phi:\mathcal{M}->\{T,F\}$

Answer (score 0):

> $\lnot x\ =\ x\nabla x$
>
> $x\lor y\ =\ \lnot(x\nabla y) = (x\nabla y)\,\nabla\,(x\nabla y)$.

Comment: Why ¬x = x∇x ? What is the meaning of ∇?

Comment: You wrote in the problem that $x\nabla y$ is equivalent to $\lnot(x\lor y)$. I assume, these symbols want to denote Boolean operations, so we have $x\lor x=x$, so
$$\lnot x=\lnot(x\lor x)=x\nabla x\,.$$